# Can we use auto keyword instead of template?

Tags: c++, templates, auto

Can we use auto keyword instead of template?

Consider following example :

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T max(T x, T y) // function template for max(T, T)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << max<int>(1, 2) << '\n'; // instantiates and calls function max<int>(int, int)
    std::cout << max<int>(4, 3) << '\n'; // calls already instantiated function max<int>(int, int)
    std::cout << max<double>(1, 2) << '\n'; // instantiates and calls function max<double>(double, double)

    return 0;
}
```

So we can write it this way too :

```
#include <iostream>


auto max(auto x, auto y) 
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << max(1, 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << max(4, 3) << '\n';
    std::cout << max(1, 2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

So, why should use auto keyword instead of template?

Comment: For brevity, if you want it. Also note that the snippets are not equivalent: the second one can take argumens of different types.

Comment: Hopefully it is clear that your first version will print a `double`, while your second version will not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought I'd seen this question asked before, but I can't seem to find it. If there isn't a target, you might want to flesh out your comment and promote it to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer to my question:
We can use abbreviated function templates if we're using the C++20 language standard. They are simpler to type and understand because they produce less syntactical clutter.

Note that our two snippets are not the same. The top one enforces that x and y are the same type, whereas the bottom one does not.

Comment: Half of the "syntactical clutter" in your Q's example is because you instantiated the template explicitly, which is not necessary. The `typename T` is deduced from the argument type(s). Template function *usage* should be no different from plain function usage if done right.

Answer (score 4):

As @HolyBlackCat said in the comment, the snippets are not the same.
In the first snippet when you use templates, you confine the arguments of `T max(T x, T y)` to be of the same type. So if you take the template approach, the following code will not work:

```
int x = 3;
double y = 5.4;
max(3, 5.4);
```

However, if you take the second approach, you can compare two different data types (if permitted, of course). This is because both argument's auto will decide what it's going to get independently, so comparing a `int` and `double` in the second approach is totally valid.